# como resolver o ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um site no wordpress que esta aparecendo esse erro

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Aquela era uma opção, então faça o seguinte, tente seguir os passos desse tutorial [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/), e se resolver coloque como resposta, explicando passo a passo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro galera tava acontecendo porque nas configurações gerais o link tava apontando para https://meudominio.com/ e dai troquei para https://www.meudominio.com/ e resolveu o problema.

Comment: Essa instalação é nova ou foi migrada de servidor? se foi migrada precisa rodar um script no banco para ajustar os links, caso contrario os `posts` podem ficar quebrados.

Comment: eu to ligado, eu rodei esses scripts